# How to implement a SUM of items

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB db which has two tables, there is the `ItemGroup` and there is the `Item`. And ItemGroup has a name and a set [] of Items, and Items hold the actual price.

I use MondoDB with NodeJS and Mongoose, my models are defined like this:

```
var itemGroupSchema = new Schema({
    title   : {type: String, required: true},
    items   : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}],
    totalp  : Number,
    date    : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var itemSchema = new Schema({
    _group  : {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'ItemGroup'},
    name   : {type: String, required: true},
    price  : Number,
    date   : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

I am open to changing my models if there is a better structure. The basic action I want t achieve is present the total price of all items in a group.

These are the things I could think of:

- Have a function in my itemGroup model that sums all the items on save.
- Have a getter in the itemGroup that sums all the items on get, totalp could be removed.
- Sum all the items just in NodeJS in a loop, and then just update the itemGroup

Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of reasonable options, mostly determined by how you're using other parts of the application.

Option 1:
Find the item IDs from your group, then use those IDs in a {$in:itemIds} aggregate query. This requires double-reads but keeps the writing to a minimum. This is useful if you're regularly updating your items. Not as useful if your primary action is to display an itemGroup

Option 2: Update the itemGroup to include a bit more cached or computed information. This could include the total price, recalculated whenever you update a corresponding item. It could also include the price for each item:
{title : 'Red items', items: [{itemId: 'I1', price: 2}, {itemId: 'I2', price : 3}] ... }

The advantage of option 2: allows brief display of data and easy recalculation of totals. Downside: every write to the itemSchema becomes a double-write to both collections. There are no transactions, so there will be points (however brief) where they are not perfectly in sync.

Option 3: Place the entire itemSchema inside the itemGroupSchema. This is fast for retrieval and fast for saving as they all come from one document. You can even index on sub-documents. It doesn't work as well if you have unbounded growth in the number of items in a group, or very very large items. Probably what I'd recommend.

Comment: Note 1: Your options 3 is interesting, because I had to make that decision earlier. I choose not to nest the items inside the group, mainly because most of the time they are accessed just as an item. The group is just secondary information, but the item is what's asked for 80% of the time. Do you think this is a good decision?

Comment: Note 2: I think your option 2 will be the best for me (+1). The data will only be updated every few hours, but reads will be constantly, so i think computed information would be the way to go. I don't know if you have any experience with Mongoose, but if so, do you maybe have a small code example on how to do the updates? Do I have a function in the group that will do the updates, or sits the function in the item, which updates the group?

Comment: I was using mongoose for a project for several months before I switched to native node mongodb. I found mongoose to use too much memory and cpu compaired to doing the queries natively.